# How to download an image from Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-staticfiles

I build a django application that generates an image and places it in a folder on the server. I want to download that image, located on the server at `example.com/generatedimages`. How do I send this image to the client? What does it have to do with static files? Do I need to generate a URL for that image temporarily? I do not use Django templating.

Technical information:

- Django 1.10
- Django Rest Framework
- ReactJs in the font-end
- jQuery for API calls
- image types: `.png` and `.svg`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is placed in `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` then it is publicly available and you can use `settings.MEDIA_URL` to create a link.

If the file is outside of `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`, you can use built-in view [django.views.static.serve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve).

If you need some protection, just use standard view but return [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects).

Serving large files through Django is not efficient. If you need large files, check [django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile).

Comment: The FileResponse does not seem to trigger a download in the browser. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't trigger a download on the server side, only in browser (by clicking a link). Browser opens an URL, you map a Django view on that URL and the view returns FileResponse with the file. Browser then opens download dialog.